# Ionic ios Emulator issue

Tags: ios, angularjs, json, ionic-framework

I am not able to start the emulator in ionic with the below commands

```
user:platforms user$ cd ..
user:example1 user$ ionic emulate ios
user:example1 user$ ionic run ios
```

Below is the package.json

```
{
  "name": "example-1",
  "version": "1.1.1",
  "description": "Example 1: An Ionic project",
  "dependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.5.6",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.0.4",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^0.3.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bower": "^1.3.3",
    "gulp-util": "^2.2.14",
    "shelljs": "^0.3.0"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
  ],
"package.json" 28L, 615C
{
  "name": "example-1",
  "version": "1.1.1",
  "description": "Example 1: An Ionic project",
  "dependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.5.6",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.0.4",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^0.3.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bower": "^1.3.3",
    "gulp-util": "^2.2.14",
    "shelljs": "^0.3.0"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
  ],
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [
    "ios"
  ]
}
```

Please let me know if you need more info. 
Please let me know if you need more info. 
Please let me know if you need more info. 
Please let me know if you need more info. Please let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you add the iOS platform, you need to build the ios version as noted here:
http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/

```
$ ionic platform add ios
$ ionic build ios
```

Perhaps that is the missing step?